# Preserving sort order of .json file that gets created from api response

Tags: python, json

I am having a problem with getting the correct sort order of a .json file that gets created from an api response using PyCharm Community Edition with python 3.7.

This is the api request:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://pokemon-go1.p.rapidapi.com/pokemon_names.json"

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "c061ae2dffmshc2a33d10b00cee7p121f42jsn11f39d53dd1e",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "pokemon-go1.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
```

If i now `print(response.text)`, I get the following output: (That's how I want my .json file to look like later)

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bulbasaur"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ivysaur"
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Venusaur"
    },
    "4": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Charmander"
    },
    "5": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Charmeleon"
    }
}
```

After that I write the response to the file "pokemondata.json" by doing this:

```
response_json = json.loads(response.text)

writeFile = open("pokemondata.json", "w")
writeFile.write(json.dumps(response_json, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
writeFile.close()
```

And then the file looks like this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bulbasaur"
    },
    "10": {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Caterpie"
    },
    "100": {
        "id": 100,
        "name": "Voltorb"
    },
    "101": {
        "id": 101,
        "name": "Electrode"
    },
    "102": {
        "id": 102,
        "name": "Exeggcute"
    }
}
```

I could not figure out how to get it done so that the file is sorted by ids (or the numbers before the id, e.g. "1") correctly. Could anybody please explain to me, how I can fix it?

Comment: You don't really need `json.loads()`. You can use `response_json = response.json()` instead. After that, you need to sort the resulting dictionary `response_json` based on your desired criteria before writing it back a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://pokemon-go1.p.rapidapi.com/pokemon_names.json"

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "c061ae2dffmshc2a33d10b00cee7p121f42jsn11f39d53dd1e",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "pokemon-go1.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

response_json = response.json()


int_keys = {int(k):v for k,v in response_json.items()}

with open("sample.json", 'w') as file_obj:
    json.dump(int_keys, file_obj, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Issue is with keys in your json which are in string format. Convert them to integers and save in the file